# C# Treat A Block Of Code As If It Were Written As Part Of A Method

Tags: python, c#

I've got an issue which I know how to solve in Python, but can't find any way to solve in C#. The issue is that I need a way to run a block of code inside a Method without hard coding that block of code into the method

For example, the block of code could be simply "return;" or it could change variables within the method, but there are a near infinite number of possibilities for what this code could be so any kind of if statement or hard coding possibilities in is out of the question

In python, the easiest way I can think of to do this would be using Eval:

```py
def Function1():
  num = 10
  Eval(MysteryCode())
  num += 1
  return num

def MysteryCode():
  return input("Write code here:  ")

print(Function1())
```

If you type "return num" as the input, it should return 10. If you wrote "num += 1", it should print 12. I won't actually be taking input from the user, but it's roughly the same as what I'm looking for

It also doesn't need to be in string format, any way to run a block of code in a method that isn't hard coded into that method works

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, I'm struggling to explain this properly :(

Comment: That is a little vague, but you are probably looking for [a Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Comment: From what I know about delegates, it can't have the method return a specific number (i.e. a delegate can't be "return 5;" and have the method it's in return 5), but I may be wrong. I know you can do it with an if statement, but I'd rather avoid hard coding any of this into the method since there are a near infinite number of possibilities of what could be contained within this code

Comment: You mean you can't have `Func<int> v = () => 5; int value = v(); Console.WriteLine(value); // printed 5` ?

Comment: No he is trying to "eval" as in JavaScript, in C#, as I said this can be done by compliling string template for this n variable, and roslyn complier. And this is an expert level, and is not used for that, in such way

Comment: @Artur You could argue that everything is "expert level" until you try it and do it yourself then? You have to learn somewhere. For all you know, OP is trying to implement a scripting language in their application. In that case a library to provide Lua scripting might be an acceptable solution if you didn't want to go full C# code compilation.

Comment: @WuzHizFace What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Being able to run arbitrary user-input code allows you to do... what? What feature does this add to your application?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I'm currently programming a game where each character (28+ and counting) has a unique ability. I would prefer to not hardcode the entire ability in each place it could occur. Currently, I'm thinking to save a block of code and refer to it somehow with a single line (ie. Python eval), since this would let me edit every single occurrence of the ability by editing that single block of code.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an interface (e.g. `ISpecialAbility`) and implementations (`KarateKick`, `Fly`, etc.) and then assign an instance of the correct ability to the character object into an `ISpecialAbility` property? Then you might end up with something like `character.SpecialAbility.Perform();`

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I don't think this works, but I think I figured it out. I don't take input from the user, so I found an Eval for C# which should be safe to use. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Composition using interfaces seems like the better option than dynamically evaluating C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stated in the comments that you want to provide special abilities to characters without hard coding the same ability every time you need it.  This sounds like the perfect time to use composition:

```cs
public class Character
{
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public ISpecialAbility Ability { get; set; }
}

public interface ISpecialAbility
{
    int SomeAction();
}

public class SomeAbility : ISpecialAbility
{
    private readonly Character _character;

    public SomeAbility(Character character)
    {
        _character = character;
    }

    public int SomeAction()
    {
        if (character.Health > 10)
            return 3;
        else
            return 5;
    }
}
```

And then when you construct a character, you can assign their special ability:

```cs
Character c = new Character();
c.Ability = new SomeAbility(c);
// Call the special ability
int result = c.Ability.SomeAction();
```

You don't necessarily need to pass the character, but I figured you *might* need a reference to it.

Alternatively, you could use a delegate:

```cs
public delegate int SpecialAbility(Character c);
```

And perhaps have some static methods:

```cs
public static int SomeAbility(Character c)
{
    if (c.Health > 10)
        return 3;
    else
        return 5;
}
```

Then your `Character` class might look like this:

```cs
public class Character
{
    private readonly SpecialAbility _specialAbility;
    public int Health { get; set; }

    public Character(SpecialAbility specialAbility)
    {
        _specialAbility = specialAbility;
    }

    public void PerformSpecialAbility()
    {
        int result = _specialAbility(this);
    }
}
```

Then you would construct your character like this:

```cs
Character c = new Character(SomeAbility);
// call special ability
c.PerformSpecialAbility();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, unlike in the example I don't actually take input from the user so I found an Eval method for C#

Here's a link to the package I ended up using: https://eval-expression.net/

To re-emphasize, this is NOT taking input from the user to run as code, as that is unsafe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).